# Retrieving answers of specific user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Question Model

```
   public function answer() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Answer');

  }
```

Answer Schema:

```
 id, question_id, user_id
```

Please help me retrieve questions with answers(eager loading) of authenticated user only. I want to do some custom query in question/answer model.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each user can have many anwsers right?

Comment: No that's not User model. This is Question model. every question should have one answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could constraint eager loading

```
$questions = App\Question::with(['answer' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('answers.user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    // Other Conditions
}]->get();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Can we do something in model without using controller to do the same?

Comment: Maybe you should check out [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: If we implement same code in view using load function then how our code would look like???

Comment: You mean call the controller from the view?